# Next build not building full html page with on demand SSG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsx

I’m having an issue while using getStaticPaths and getStaticProps to have an on demand SSG for a sharing page. I'm using Next v12.1.0 and React 17.0.2.
When I build a particular /[id] page, I get the data but the HTML is not building as it should. Here's the code:

- Code from page/[postId].tsx:

```
const PostShare: NextPage = ({ metadata }: any): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta name="og:description" content="content shared via page" />
        <meta name="og:title" content={metadata.title} />
        <meta name="og:type" content={metadata.type} />
        <meta name="og:image" content={metadata.image} />
        <meta name="description" content="content shared via page" />

        <title>Page | Share</title>
      </Head>

      <main className="min-h-screen min-w-screen bg-js-carta grid flex-col place-content-center">
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center mb-[2vh] md:mb-[3vh]">
            <div className="relative w-[40vw] max-w-[380px] aspect-square mb-[20px] md:mb-[35px]">
              <Image
                src={"/assets/logo.svg"}
                layout="fill"
                alt={"log"}
              />
            </div>
            <h1 className="mb-[20px] md:mb-[35px] text-white font-semibold text-3xl">Redirection ...</h1>
            <p className="mb-[35px] text-white w-[90vw] text-[14px] md:w-[38vw] text-center md:text-[17px] font-normal leading-9">Some text/p>
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col justify-between items-center w-[90%] md:w-[40vw] m-auto max-w-[435px]">
            <a href={metadata?.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" className="w-full p-5 md:p-6 rounded-xl bg-white text-js-carta text-center text-[15px] font-bold mb-[20px] md:mb-[30px]">Some Link</a>
            <div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center mb-[20px] md:mb-[30px]">
              <div className="h-[1px] bg-[#9894b5] w-[20%] md:w-[20%] lg:w-[28%]"></div>     
              <p className="text-center text-white text-[13px] font-normal md:text-[15px]">Some text</p>
              <div className="h-[1px] bg-[#9894b5] w-[20%] md:w-[20%] lg:w-[28%]"></div>
            </div>
            <a href={`https://www.page.com/post/${metadata.id}`} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" className="w-full p-5 md:p-6 rounded-xl bg-white text-js-carta text-center text-[15px] font-bold mb-[10px]">Go</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [{ params: { postId: '1' } }, { params: { postId: '2' } }],    
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
};

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const postId: number = parseInt(params?.postId.toString());

  const { data: metadata, error } = await getContentMetadataForShareRequest(postId);

  return {
    props: {
      metadata,
    },
  };
};
```

This should create a new page once I request another id like I do on this test (this is an id of a post that I know of):

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [{ params: { postId: '4042' } }],    
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
};

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const postId: number = parseInt(params?.postId.toString());

  const { data: metadata, error } = await getContentMetadataForShareRequest(postId);

  return {
    props: {
      metadata,
    },
  };
};
```

In here we can expect an html file called 4042.html to be created with all the data from the api, but somehow it's just building an almost empty html file:

- Code from .next/server/pages/page/4042.html:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charSet="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta name="next-head-count" content="2" />
  <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/c9566ae84cfa64c1.css" as="style" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/c9566ae84cfa64c1.css" data-n-g="" /><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
  <script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-5cd94c89d3acac5f.js"></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-eaae93af0b2e8468.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-a070cbfff3c750c5.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-ef558cc4c27e2f83.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-2c36286d803ff756.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/page/%5BpostId%5D-5c7db38fec69463d.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/9uNXtvnNpkvbdeI6xP2KX/_buildManifest.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/9uNXtvnNpkvbdeI6xP2KX/_ssgManifest.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/9uNXtvnNpkvbdeI6xP2KX/_middlewareManifest.js" defer=""></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="__next" data-reactroot=""></div>
  <script id="__NEXT_DATA__"
    type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{"metadata":{"id":4042,"title":"Des batteries presque éternelles à partir de déchets nucléaires !","type":"Multi (ex: article + vidéo)","url":"https://www.futura-sciences.com/tech/actualites/technologie-batteries-presque-eternelles-partir-dechets-nucleaires-65354/","image":"imageURlHiddenForObviousReasons","domain_name":"futura-sciences.com"}},"__N_SSG":true},"page":"/page/[postId]","query":{"postId":"4042"},"buildId":"someBuildId","isFallback":false,"gsp":true,"scriptLoader":[]}</script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I'm getting the needed data but it's not passed into the html as it should. Well, the page itself is basically empty when I build it.

I've tried everything and searched everywhere I could think of but nothing seems to be working.
If you guys have an idea of what could be the issue it would be super appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was the Redux Persist gate causing the issue. I disabled it for that particular page and everything started working as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue but I am not using Redux... Could anyone help me with that ?!